# JavaScript - map, filter, reduce. Converting from Arrays to Deeper Trees

Tags: javascript, lodash

Each video has an interesting moments collection, each representing a time during which a screenshot is interesting or representative of the title as a whole. Notice that both the boxarts and interestingMoments arrays are located at the same depth in the tree. Retrieve the time of the middle interesting moment and the smallest box art url simultaneously with `Array.zip()` . Return an {id, title, time, url} object for each video. **Anyone can help with** `Array.zip()` ?

```
const movieLists = [
    {
        name: "New Releases",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 213432 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 64534 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 323133 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
                    { width: 140, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" }

                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 54654754 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 43524243 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 6575665 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Instant Queue",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 130, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 132423 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 54637425 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 3452343 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
                    { width: 120, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
                    { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 45632456 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 234534 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 3453434 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

Array.zip = function(boxarts, interestingMoments, combinerFunction) {
    let counter,
        results = [];

    for(counter = 0; counter < Math.min(boxarts.length, interestingMoments.length); counter++) {
        results.push(combinerFunction(boxarts[counter],interestingMoments[counter]));
    }

    return results;
};


let arr1 = movieLists.map(function(movieList) {
    return movieList.videos.map(function(video) {
        return Array.zip(
            video.boxarts.reduce(function(acc,curr) {
                if (acc.width * acc.height < curr.width * curr.height) {
                        return acc;
                }
                else {
                      return curr;
                }
              }),
            video.interestingMoments.filter(function(interestingMoment) {
                return interestingMoment.type === "Middle";
            }),
              function(boxart, interestingMoment) {
                return {id: video.id, title: video.title, time: interestingMoment.time, url: boxart.url};
              });
    });
});

// //to enable deep level flatten use recursion with reduce and concat
let concatArr = (function flattenDeep(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
})(arr1);

console.log(concatArr)
```

**SOLUTION WITHOUT** `Array.zip()` . **Anyone can help with** `Array.zip()` ?

```
let arr1 = movieLists.map(function (movieList) {
    return movieList.videos.map(function (v) {
        return {
            id: v.id,
            title: v.title,
            time: v.interestingMoments
                .reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
                    if (currentValue.type === "Middle") {
                        return accumulator = currentValue
                    }
                }).time,
            url: v.boxarts.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                var area = currentValue.width * currentValue.height;
                if (area < accumulator.area) {
                    return { area: area, url: currentValue.url };
                }
                return accumulator;
            }, { area: 10000000, url: '' }).url
        }
    });
});

let concatArr = (function flattenDeep(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
})(arr1);

console.log(concatArr)
```

**Solution Result**
[image]

**SOLUTION** with `_.zipWith` - Lodash

```
var _ = require('lodash');

    let arr1 = movieLists.map(function(movieList) {
        return movieList.videos.map(function(video) {
            return _.zipWith(
                [video.boxarts.reduce(function(acc,curr) {
                    if (acc.width * acc.height < curr.width * curr.height) {
                            return acc;
                    }
                    else {
                          return curr;
                    }
                  })],
                video.interestingMoments.filter(function(interestingMoment) {
                    return interestingMoment.type === "Middle";
                }),
                  function(boxart, interestingMoment) {
                    return {id: video.id, title: video.title, time: interestingMoment.time, url: boxart.url};
                  });
        });
    });

    //to enable deep level flatten use recursion with reduce and concat
    let concatArr = (function flattenDeep(arr1) {
        return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
    })(arr1);

    console.log(concatArr)
```

Comment: for "smallest box art url" could we define smallest as lowest width x height (area).

Comment: @Jamiec yes, lowest area.

Comment: @Slai Solution Result updated. I uploaded wrong image. It looks lke code is working fine but i want to implement it with Array.zip()

Comment: zip doesn't quite make sense to me in this case, as the arrays have different size (2 and 3), and I don't see relation between them. I think zip would make more sense if combining for example array of 3 moments with array of 3 screenshots for each of the 3 moments.

Comment: @Slai mistake corrected. Thank you for pointing it out. The reason I want to implement it as Array.zip() just as an initial requirement. Your solution makes sense and is much shorter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for your code to be so complicated. A simple `find` for the moment, and `reduce` to determine the largest area will suffice:

```
var result = movieLists[0].videos.map(v => {
   return {
     id: v.id,
     title: v.title,
     time: v.interestingMoments.find(m => m.type === "Middle").time,
     url: v.boxarts.reduce( (p,c) => {
         var area = c.width*c.height;
         if(area < p.area){
           return {area:area, url: c.url};
         }
         return p;
     },{area:10000000, url:''}).url
   }
});
```

Live example below:

```js
const movieLists = [
    {
        name: "New Releases",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 213432 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 64534 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 323133 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
                    { width: 140, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" }

                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 54654754 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 43524243 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 6575665 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Instant Queue",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 130, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 132423 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 54637425 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 3452343 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture",
                "boxarts": [
                    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
                    { width: 120, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
                    { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" }
                ],
                "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "interestingMoments": [
                    { type: "End", time: 45632456 },
                    { type: "Start", time: 234534 },
                    { type: "Middle", time: 3453434 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
var result = movieLists[0].videos.map(v => {
   return {
     id: v.id,
     title: v.title,
     time: v.interestingMoments.find(m => m.type === "Middle").time,
     url: v.boxarts.reduce( (p,c) => {
         var area = c.width*c.height;
         if(area < p.area){
           return {area:area, url: c.url};
         }
         return p;
     },{area:10000000, url:''}).url
   }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it works perfectly ! i was wondering when I am changing `find()` to `filter()` I am getting undefined data , not sure why . Going back to my original question why `Array.zip()` is giving me undefined data. There reason I am insisteing on using `Array.zip()` this was a condition at school.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced version (pun intended) if `JSON.parse` is used to get the data:

```js
var result = [], j = '[{"name":"New Releases","videos":[{"id":70111470,"title":"Die Hard","boxarts":[{"width":150,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg"},{"width":200,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg"}],"url":"http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470","rating":4,"interestingMoments":[{"type":"End","time":213432},{"type":"Start","time":64534},{"type":"Middle","time":323133}]},{"id":654356453,"title":"Bad Boys","boxarts":[{"width":200,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg"},{"width":140,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg"}],"url":"http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470","rating":5,"interestingMoments":[{"type":"End","time":54654754},{"type":"Start","time":43524243},{"type":"Middle","time":6575665}]}]},{"name":"Instant Queue","videos":[{"id":65432445,"title":"The Chamber","boxarts":[{"width":130,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg"},{"width":200,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg"}],"url":"http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470","rating":4,"interestingMoments":[{"type":"End","time":132423},{"type":"Start","time":54637425},{"type":"Middle","time":3452343}]},{"id":675465,"title":"Fracture","boxarts":[{"width":200,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"},{"width":120,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg"},{"width":300,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"}],"url":"http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470","rating":5,"interestingMoments":[{"type":"End","time":45632456},{"type":"Start","time":234534},{"type":"Middle","time":3453434}]}]}]';

JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => !v.id ? v : result.push({ id: v.id, title: v.title,
  url: v.boxarts.reduce((a, b) => a.width * a.height < b.width * b.height ? a : b).url, 
  time: v.interestingMoments.find(m => m.type === "Middle").time }));

console.log( result );
```